# Error calling Apex imperatively from LWC in a JavaScript method. Error gotten -> [F.default(...).then(...).error is not a function],

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript, lwc-wire-adapter, imperativeapex

This is the import statement on my LWC

```
import checkSize from '@salesforce/apex/XFiles.checkSize';
```

This is what the function looks like on my lwc

```
handleCheckingFileSize(fileId) {
    let resultSize = {}

    checkSize({docId: fileId})
    .then(result => {
        resultSize = result 
    })
    .error(error => {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Error checking file size',
                    message: error.body.message,
                    variant: 'error'
                })
            );
    })  
    return resultSize
}
```

and this is what it looks like when I tried debugging on my browser

```
handleCheckingFileSize(e) {
                let t = {};
                return F.default({
                    docId: e
                }).then(e=>{
                    t = e
                }
                ).error(e=>{
                    this.dispatchEvent(new c.ShowToastEvent({
                        title: "Error checking file size",
                        message: e.body.message,
                        variant: "error"
                    }))
                }
                ),
                t
            }
```

and this is what it looks like on Apex

```
public class XFiles {
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
   public static CheckSizeResponse checkSize(String docId) {
        CheckSizeResponse fileResponse = new CheckSizeResponse();

        return fileResponse;
    }
}
```

But for some special reasons, I keep on getting this error on my browser "[F.default(...).then(...).error is not a function]" can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't actually any [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).error function. Instead it's [Promise.catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch), So you should just replace,

```
checkSize({docId: fileId})
    .then(result => {
        resultSize = result 
    })
    .error(error => {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Error checking file size',
                    message: error.body.message,
                    variant: 'error'
                })
            );
    })
```

with,

```
checkSize({docId: fileId})
    .then(result => {
        resultSize = result 
    })
    .catch(error => {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Error checking file size',
                    message: error.body.message,
                    variant: 'error'
                })
            );
    })
```

There isn't any special reason actually. And it should start working. :)